# Comparing today's date with a future date causes unary operator error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to compare a date in the future with today's date. If today's date is greater than the expiry date then 'Date has Expired' should be displayed. With the following code I get the following error: `[: 1445783380: unary operator expected` - I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.- Any ideas?

```
        expireDate='2025-10-25 16:17:51'
        #format the expireDate date so it can be compared
        expireLoadGen=$(date -d $expireDate +%s)

       if [ $(date +%s) -gt $expireLoadGen ] 
        then        
        echo "Date has Expired"
        else
        echo "Date has not Expired"
       fi
```

Comment: Maybe `$expireLoadGen` is empty. Did you do any debugging?

Comment: That's because you missed quotes: `expireLoadGen=$(date -d "$expireDate" +%s)` with mandatory quotes in the expansion of `$expireDate`!

Comment: Try adding `echo $expireLoadGen` - this may give you a hint. Or checking `$?` after you set it.

Comment: put `set -x` at the beginning of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
expireDate='2025-10-25 16:17:51'
expireLoadGen=$(date -d "$expireDate" +%s)

if [ `date +%s` -gt $expireLoadGen ]; then
        echo "Date has Expired"
else
        echo "Date has not Expired"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The lack of quotes was the answer